# Safari overflow issue - OSX

Tags: html, css, safari, webkit

https://plnkr.co/edit/yr5ugYHKbuOmOEssGg93?p=preview

This is a simplified example of my main menu.

The `menuList` has `overflow-y: auto` applied because I need it's contents to scroll on small screens. However, applying this style seems to prevent Safari from rendering the submenu. No `overflow-x` setting seems to fix it. This is only an issue on Safari on OSX.